# vb.net open multiple excel files in invisible mode

Tags: vb.net, excel

This is my code to open multiple excel file to do some calculation based on their content.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim w As Excel.Worksheet

    xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlApp.Visible = True

    wb1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("E:\xls\f.xls")
    wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("E:\xls\b.xls")
    w = wb1.ActiveSheet


End Sub

End Module
```

This code runs and it's ok,but i want to not show excel application and i uncomment the line that set `xlApp.Visible=True` .but this exception occures:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in ConsoleApplication12.exe

Additional information: The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))

So,What do i have to do?

Comment: Have you tried `xlApp.Visible = False` ??

Comment: Yes,the Same exception.